# AWS Cognito with external user database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to save the user details in the local database then AWS having its own internal database in following two scenarios:

1. User mobile number/ email is not verified
2. Mobile number/ email id is verified.

Comment: Can you give more details? Do you want to store part of user details in local database and only use cognito for getting authentication token?

Comment: @YuHuang yeah, I am looking for username, mobile number, to be in my local database but auth token from Cognito.

Comment: I have also explored for `Keyclock`, but there is no native support for mobile verification with two factor authentication like one time password.

Comment: Can I say that you just want to migrate your existing username and mobile number data to Cognito?

Comment: I don't have an existing database, I though I will use Cognito to validate the users which are getting registered in the application (as it provides existing flow to validate email, mobile number), but will keep some information in my local database.

Comment: and for every request I will check with Cognito if the token passed is valid or not

Comment: If you just want to save extra info in your local database, you can use Cognito's post authentication trigger for storing data after user successfully login, or use Pre sign-up authentication to store data before user sign up. You need to write lambda function to implement these trigger.

Comment: @YuHuang that was helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178365/discussion-between-yu-huang-and-vishrant).